# Cordova navigator.mediaSession

Tags: android, cordova, navigator

I a trying to get media controls working on Android when playing audio.

I originally was using html5 audio, but then moved to using cordova-plugin-media to play the audio, and used music-controls which is a cordova plugin for the controls. (I actually tried quite a few different plugins etc). The issue I had was that none of the plugins worked 100%, I was still able to find ways to pause audio etc on the device without it calling my callbacks to keep my app in sync. I have now given up with this approach after many days of troubleshooting.

I was reading an article yesterday and found out about navigator.mediaSession and was able to get it up and running inside of google chrome on desktop by switching back to html5 audo, however, navigator.mediaSession is not defined when I build it through cordova.

Is it possible to use naviator.mediaSession through cordova? If so what am I missing?

If not, then it's back to pulling my hair out. If anyone has any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, my device browser is chrome 81, which should have mediaSession.

Comment: As per the navigator link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator , Navigator.mediasession is not supported for Android webview. So I m afraid what you are trying will work and also I could see mediasession is in  experimental mode as per the link. I feel plugins is the way to go.

Comment: Did you had a look at the comment by any chance?

Comment: @Gandhi Thanks for the info, annoyingly I am yet to find a plugin that works.

Comment: huge bounty miss :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, Navigator.mediaSession don't work in cordova as Android webview don't support them. You can find more info on this under the browser compatibility section of [Navigator API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) Infact, mediaSession itself is in experimental mode as of now.

The best bet is to go with cordova plugins and enhance them according to your need. As you mentioned there are quite a few plugins exclusively for media and music controls. To name a few,

https://github.com/homerours/cordova-music-controls-plugin

https://github.com/521dimensions/cordova-music-controls-plugin

Plugins is the right approach to proceed is what I would say.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. you can use ionic, ionic is open-source SDK for hybrid mobile app and exist cordova-plugin-media on it, and it support all platform Android-Ios-Windows-Browser. even you can use react for ability to record and play back audio files on a device. plz see below link maybe help you:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media

and for local notifications you can use this link:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/local-notifications/

or you can embed a Cordova-enabled WebView component within a larger Android application via this link:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/webview.html

and then you can use cordova plugin media:

1. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media
2. https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview